# No Code Signing Certificated Found

Tags: ios, xcode, keychain

I just installed the new Apple Signing Certificate, but for whatever reason some issues came up. I am using iOS App Signer for a few apps I sideload, so after replacing the Signing Certificate, an error appears in iOS App Signer - "No Code Signing Certificates Found".

I thought that if I modified my iPhone Developer certificate directly in the Keychain to "Always Trust" it would work. Indeed, it does work and gets found by the iOS App Signer, but when I try to side load Provenance, for example, [image: http://i.imgur.com/vSxAYtp.png]

this error comes up, due to the "Always Trust" being enabled. If I change it to "Use System Defaults" it works like a charm, but then iOS App Signer cannot find a Signing Certificate.

I would really appreciate any help with this matter! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

As error logs suggest that your Parent Application(Main Application) contains child application (Target of Extension or Apple Watch App). Here issue is that you are not using same certificate for code signing for both of them. Please check `Code signing` in `Build Settings` and make sure both target using same certificate(iPhone Developer : Chris Breuer).